# Greco-Roman egalitarianism

Tags: lateral-thinking

[Athenian democracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athenian_democracy)
is a cornerstone of egalitarianism.  One person, one vote.  Everyone.

Here's something, though, Athenians mightn't've imagined:

```
                      I =    II =    III
        IV =   V =   VI =   VII =   VIII
        IX =   X =   XI =   XII =   XIII
       XIV =  XV =  XVI =  XVII =  XVIII =  IL =  L =  LI =  LII =  LIII
       XIX =  XX =  XXI =  XXII =  XXIII =  ... ?
      XXIV = XXV = XXVI = XXVII = XXVIII =  ... ?
      XXIX = XXX = XXXI = XXXII = XXXIII =  ... ?
```

**Can you imagine it?**

Please fill in the right side `... ?`s and explain.

Comment: Apology for the lack of more specific tags: They would give away the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Equal numbers are those with

> equal products of Roman numerals

so the blanks are

> IC = C = CI = CII = CIII
> ID = D = DI = DII = DIII
> IM = M = MI = MII = MIII

Comment: @humn Is IL a valid Roman numeral?

Comment: Got me. @noedne! Formally it would be XLIX, which would overflow.

Comment: The ancient Romans never bothered (as far as the surviving sources tell us) to agree on a particular authoritative specification for how their notation for numbers worked -- and in the absence of that, speaking about "valid" representations misses the point somewhat. It's certainly true that the _modern_ tradition tends to frown on notations such as IL, but the actual Roman practice was less rigid than that. (For example there is apparently one attested use of [XXCIIII for 84](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2879758/14366)).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Very interesting!